# Value of optional type 'Float?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I define a class in Swift like the following:

```
var moduleName : String?
var moduleWeight : Float = 0
var moduleMark : Double = 0.0
var moduleCompletion : Int = 0
var moduleNotes : String?
```

I have another function that accesses these variables

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    //

    if segue.identifier == "courseWorkTopView"
    {
        if let topViewController = segue.destination as? assignmentTopViewController{
            topViewController.moduleName = detailItem?.moduleName
            topViewController.moduleWeight = detailItem?.value
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> Value of optional type 'Float?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

I tried the following code as well

```
topViewController.moduleWeight = (detailItem?.value)!
```

But I get a run time error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

I'm new to swift and it will be great if someone could help to fix this issue

Comment: FYI - just about anytime Xcode suggests using `!` or `?`, it's leading you to bad code. I really wish Apple would fix that "feature" of Xcode. Half the Swift questions here are caused by that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can solve like that

```
topViewController.moduleWeight = detailItem?.value ?? 0
```

**or change**  moduleWeight as `optional`

```
var moduleWeight : Float?
```

and use it normal

```
topViewController.moduleWeight = detailItem?.value
```

Answer (score 1):

`detailItem` is nil. If you want to avoid the crash, you can use

```
topViewController.moduleWeight = detailItem?.value ?? 0
```

(or use any other reasonable default), or do

```
 if let topViewController = segue.destination as? assignmentTopViewController, let detail = detailItem {
    topViewController.moduleName = detail.moduleName
    topViewController.moduleWeight = detail.value
 }
```